# Video initialize error Flutter, video_player

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I faced such a problem that when my video in the video_player widget is initialized, such an backtrace comes out from flutter, after which the initialization stops and the video does not load. Someone know how to fix that? I have tried to use chewieplayer, but it doesn't works, also fijkplayer, which is not working too...

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl(13139): Init ada837c [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.1] [generic_x86_arm, sdk_gphone_x86_arm, Google, 30]
D/MetadataUtil(13139): Skipped unknown metadata entry: ������
I/OMXClient(13139): IOmx service obtained
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): connecting to surface 0xea892e58, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec(13139): [OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder] setting surface generation to 13454357
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): disconnecting from surface 0xea892e58, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): connecting to surface 0xea892e58, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
E/ACodec  (13139): [OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010
I/ACodec  (13139): codec does not support config priority (err -1010)
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): disconnecting from surface 0xea892e58, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): connecting to surface 0xea892e58, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): set up nativeWindow 0xea892e58 for 540x1020, color 0x13, rotation 0, usage 0x1002900
D/CCodec  (13139): allocate(c2.android.aac.decoder)
I/CCodec  (13139): Created component [c2.android.aac.decoder]
W/ACodec  (13139): [OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder] BAD CODEC: Output format changed unexpectedly from (diff) AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
W/ACodec  (13139):       int32_t color-standard = 1
W/ACodec  (13139):       int32_t android._dataspace = 260
W/ACodec  (13139):     } to (diff) AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
W/ACodec  (13139):       int32_t color-standard = 86
W/ACodec  (13139):       int32_t android._dataspace = 258
W/ACodec  (13139):     }
D/CCodecConfig(13139): read media type: audio/mp4a-latm
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(13139): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.max-count.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(13139): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.subscribed-indices.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(13139): extent() != 1 for single value type: input.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(13139): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(13139): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(13139): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater(13139): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.pool-ids.values
I/CCodecConfig(13139): query failed after returning 19 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/CCodecConfig(13139): c2 config diff is Dict {
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::u32 coded.aac-packaging.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::u32 coded.bitrate.value = 64000
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::u32 coded.pl.level = 0
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::u32 coded.pl.profile = 8192
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::i32 coding.drc.album-mode.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::float coding.drc.attenuation-factor.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::float coding.drc.boost-factor.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::i32 coding.drc.compression-mode.value = 3
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::i32 coding.drc.effect-type.value = 3
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::float coding.drc.encoded-level.value = 0.25
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::float coding.drc.reference-level.value = -16
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::u32 input.buffers.max-size.value = 8192
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::u32 input.delay.value = 0
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   string input.media-type.value = "audio/mp4a-latm"
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::u32 output.delay.value = 2
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::float output.drc.output-loudness.value = 0.25
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   string output.media-type.value = "audio/raw"
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::u32 raw.channel-count.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::u32 raw.max-channel-count.value = 8
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::u32 raw.sample-rate.value = 44100
D/CCodecConfig(13139): }
D/CCodec  (13139): [c2.android.aac.decoder] buffers are bound to CCodec for this session
D/CCodecConfig(13139): no c2 equivalents for flags
D/CCodecConfig(13139): config failed => CORRUPTED
W/Codec2Client(13139): query -- param skipped: index = 1107298332.
D/CCodec  (13139): client requested max input size 299, which is smaller than what component recommended (8192); overriding with component recommendation.
W/CCodec  (13139): This behavior is subject to change. It is recommended that app developers double check whether the requested max input size is in reasonable range.
D/CCodec  (13139): setup formats input: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-drc-album-mode = 0
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-drc-boost-level = 127
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-drc-cut-level = 127
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-drc-effect-type = 3
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-drc-heavy-compression = 3
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-encoded-target-level = -1
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-max-output-channel_count = 8
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-target-ref-level = 64
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t channel-count = 1
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t level = 0
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t max-input-size = 8192
D/CCodec  (13139):   string mime = "audio/mp4a-latm"
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t profile = 2
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t sample-rate = 44100
D/CCodec  (13139): } and output: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-drc-album-mode = 0
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-drc-boost-level = 127
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-drc-cut-level = 127
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-drc-effect-type = 3
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-drc-heavy-compression = 3
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-drc-output-loudness = -1
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-encoded-target-level = -1
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-max-output-channel_count = 8
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t aac-target-ref-level = 64
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t channel-count = 1
D/CCodec  (13139):   string mime = "audio/raw"
D/CCodec  (13139):   int32_t sample-rate = 44100
D/CCodec  (13139): }
W/Codec2Client(13139): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
W/Codec2Client(13139): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
W/Codec2Client(13139): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
E/FMQ     (13139): grantorIdx must be less than 3
E/FMQ     (13139): grantorIdx must be less than 3
D/CCodecBufferChannel(13139): [c2.android.aac.decoder#39] Created input block pool with allocatorID 16 => poolID 27 - OK (0)
I/CCodecBufferChannel(13139): [c2.android.aac.decoder#39] Created output block pool with allocatorID 16 => poolID 311 - OK
D/CCodecBufferChannel(13139): [c2.android.aac.decoder#39] Configured output block pool ids 311 => OK
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0(13139): bufferpool2 0xefbcd288 : 0(0 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 1/7 (recycle/alloc) - 6/14 (fetch/transfer)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0(13139): Destruction - bufferpool2 0xefbcd288 cached: 0/0M, 0/0% in use; allocs: 7, 14% recycled; transfers: 14, 57% unfetched
E/FMQ     (13139): grantorIdx must be less than 3
E/FMQ     (13139): grantorIdx must be less than 3
D/CCodecConfig(13139): c2 config diff is   c2::i32 coding.drc.compression-mode.value = 1
D/CCodecConfig(13139):   c2::u32 raw.channel-count.value = 2
D/CCodecBuffers(13139): [c2.android.aac.decoder#39:Output[N]] popFromStashAndRegister: output format changed to AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   int32_t aac-drc-album-mode = 0
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   int32_t aac-drc-boost-level = 127
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   int32_t aac-drc-cut-level = 127
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   int32_t aac-drc-effect-type = 3
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   int32_t aac-drc-heavy-compression = 1
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   int32_t aac-drc-output-loudness = -1
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   int32_t aac-encoded-target-level = -1
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   int32_t aac-max-output-channel_count = 8
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   int32_t aac-target-ref-level = 64
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   int32_t channel-count = 2
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   string mime = "audio/raw"
D/CCodecBuffers(13139):   int32_t sample-rate = 44100
D/CCodecBuffers(13139): }
E/IAudioFlinger(13139): createTrack returned error -12
E/AudioTrack(13139): createTrack_l(1149589744): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12 output 0
E/AudioTrack-JNI(13139): Error -12 initializing AudioTrack
D/AudioTrack(13139): gather(): no metrics gathered, track status=-12
E/android.media.AudioTrack(13139): Error code -20 when initializing AudioTrack.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecAudioRenderer error, index=1, format=Format(null, null, null, audio/raw, null, -1, null, [-1, -1, -1.0], [2, 44100]), format_supported=YES
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:566)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioSink$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed 0 Config(44100, 12, 44100)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink$Configuration.buildAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:2092)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink.buildAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:1070)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink.buildAudioTrackWithRetry(DefaultAudioSink.java:1049)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink.initializeAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:846)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink.handleBuffer(DefaultAudioSink.java:929)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.MediaCodecAudioRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioRenderer.java:703)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1894)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:792)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:989)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:490)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       ... 3 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot create AudioTrack
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at android.media.AudioTrack$Builder.build(AudioTrack.java:1277)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink$Configuration.createAudioTrackV29(DefaultAudioSink.java:2141)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink$Configuration.createAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:2119)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink$Configuration.buildAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:2084)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13139):       ... 12 more
D/CCodecBuffers(13139): [c2.android.aac.decoder#39:1D-Output.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 0
D/CCodecBuffers(13139): [c2.android.aac.decoder#39:1D-Output.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 1
D/CCodecBuffers(13139): [c2.android.aac.decoder#39:1D-Output.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 2
D/CCodecBuffers(13139): [c2.android.aac.decoder#39:1D-Output.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 3
I/CCodecConfig(13139): query failed after returning 19 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/CCodecConfig(13139): c2 config diff is   c2::i32 coding.drc.compression-mode.value = 3
W/Codec2Client(13139): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
W/Codec2Client(13139): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
W/Codec2Client(13139): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): connecting to surface 0xea8960b8, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec(13139): [OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder] setting surface generation to 13454358
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): disconnecting from surface 0xea8960b8, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): connecting to surface 0xea8960b8, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): disconnecting from surface 0xea8960b8, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): connecting to surface 0xea8960b8, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): set up nativeWindow 0xea8960b8 for 540x1020, color 0x13, rotation 0, usage 0x1002900
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): disconnecting from surface 0xea892e58, reason disconnectFromSurface
D/MetadataUtil(13139): Skipped unknown metadata entry: ������
D/CCodecBufferChannel(13139): [c2.android.aac.decoder#39] MediaCodec discarded an unknown buffer
I/chatty  (13139): uid=10153(com.crocodile) identical 2 lines
D/CCodecBufferChannel(13139): [c2.android.aac.decoder#39] MediaCodec discarded an unknown buffer
I/hw-BpHwBinder(13139): onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients
D/SurfaceUtils(13139): disconnecting from surface 0xea8960b8, reason disconnectFromSurface
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I have the same irritating problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be the video codecs friend. Try using another format of the same video (with Format Factory u can try different formats). In my case I had to change the video I was going to use as background for my web site.

A different known issue, that may be a problem is the restriction imposed by web browsers that prevents u from starting videos programmatically with volume on. To solve the web browser's issue, set always the video's volume to 0.

U can see further detail on this answer: [Video not playing in flutter web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68712249/video-not-playing-in-flutter-web-application).

Hope it helps...Happy coding y'all